# Django REST Framework filter backend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to implement some basic filtering on my GenericAPIView, like this:

- view:

  ```
  class OperatorList(generics.GenericAPIView):

      permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsAdmin)

      filter_class = OperatorsFilter
      serializer_class = OperatorSerializer

      def get_queryset(self):
          queryset = self.request.user.operators.all()

      def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          serializer = OperatorSerializer(instance=self.get_queryset(),
                                      many=True,
                                      context=self.get_serializer_context())
          return Response(serializer.data)
  ```
- serializer:

  ```
  class OperatorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = Operator
          fields = ['id', 'name', 'created', ]
  ```
- filter set:

  ```
  import rest_framework_filters
  from rest_framework import filters
  from .models import Operator


  class OperatorFilter(filters.FilterSet):

      created = rest_framework_filters.DateTimeField(lookup_type='gte')

      class Meta:
          model = Operator
          fields = ('name', 'created', )
  ```

The issue is that filters are displayed in browsable API, but 'Created' is not a `DateTimeWidget`, but a simple input.
Also, applying filter takes no effect, and I still have to catch `request.query_params` in `get_queryset()` (I ama trying to use filter backend to avoid this in first turn).

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you've subclassed `GenericAPIView` and then not (re-)implemented any of the *handy logic* that Django REST Framework provides in its concrete view class.

Instead you want to subclass [`ListAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) which provides a `get` method implementing the filtering behaviour you're looking for.

The *magic* all resides in [`ListModelMixin`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L39) which filters the queryset as needed...

```
class ListModelMixin(object):
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        ... method continues ...
```

Your final view class should then look something like this:

```
class OperatorList(generics.ListAPIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsAdmin)

    filter_class = OperatorsFilter
    serializer_class = OperatorSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.request.user.operators.all()
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm glad. PPs on the docs to improve them are ALWAYS welcomed :-)